# How can I get Node module completions support?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

VS Code doesn't seem to know what `connect` or `express` or `io` are. Can I tell it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get definition files from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped or with the tsd-tool. For, let's say express, download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/master/express/express.d.ts and add this to your source file: `/// <reference path="myPathTo/express.d.ts" />`.

You will most likely end up with a bunch of `d.ts`-files so you could have one meta-d.ts-file which references all of them and which is referenced by your sources.

```
/// <reference path="fileA.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="fileB.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="fileC.d.ts" />
```

and the in your sources do this

```
/// <reference path="references.d.ts" />
```

Comment: I tried adding a reference to `express.d.ts` but I still didn't get any completions for `express.`. How does it know to match `require('express')` with the `.d.ts` file?

Comment: VSCode knows by ```express.d.ts``` declaring the module like so ```declare module "express" {```. Note that express is a function so ```express.``` will only complete function properties like call, apply etc. Try ```express().``` to see a list of completions

Comment: Weird. Wasn't working with the project I tried it on yesterday, but it seems to be working better now.  Thank you! That [tsd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd) tool is nice too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the documentation says about this.

> You can get IntelliSense for many popular Node frameworks by incorporating TypeScript Definition files into your workspace. A
>   TypeScript Definition (TSD) describes the API you are consuming in
>   TypeScript, but it does not implement the API.
>
> Visual Studio Code reads TSDs and in turn provides a rich IntelliSense
>   experience based on the metadata provided by the definition. While you
>   could use tsd to search for and install TypeScript definitions, VSCode
>   provides a Quick Assist to automate the process.
>
> Open app.js and notice that __dirname (lines 14, 23) have a green
>   underline, indicating a warning. Click on __dirname and press Ctrl+.
>   to open the Quick Fix context menu and choose Add /// reference to
>   /node/node.d.ts.

Follow the directions here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/nodejs

Essentially, the steps are to:

1. Get a TypeScript definition file and include it
2. Or generate the TypeScript typing using some help from VSCode

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to pull down the tsd file and reference it with the `///` syntax in the file.

Another option is to use TypeScript on the server.

This will get easier

Answer (score 0):

"The TypeScript Definition Manager (TSD) makes it easy to search for and install TypeScript definition files into your Visyual Studio Code workspace. This tool will download the requested definition from the DefinitelyTyped repository."

Install tsd via npm:

```
npm install tsd -g
```

Then install whatever you need, so pull down the Node and Express definitions.:

```
tsd query node express --action install
```

Here is a [link to more info](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/)

Comment: tsd is now deprecated.  Better to use "typings" instead.